# How to run different scenarios in Omnet++ (Veins)?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo, traffic-simulation

I have created a traffic scenario in SUMO and running it using Omnet++. I have Inet, Veins and VANET to work with it. I made vehicles as a nodes and run the scenario using Veins, and established the communication between the nodes using VANET. But I have 3 different scenarios in SUMO and I have to run them in Veins so how can I run multiple scenarios? Is it possible using single Veins_Inet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create three different configs in your `omnetpp.ini`, each of them loading a different SUMO configuration:

```
[Config FirstConfig]
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("firstSquare.launchd.xml")

[Config SecondConfig]
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("secondSquare.launchd.xml")

[Config ThirdConfig]
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("thirdSquare.launchd.xml")
```

Then you start them with

```
./run -u Cmdenv -c FirstConfig -r 0
./run -u Cmdenv -c SecondConfig -r 0
./run -u Cmdenv -c ThirdConfig -r 0
```

Comment: [Config FirstConfig] is repeated which should be [Config SecondConfig] and [Config ThirdConfig].

Comment: Thank you @MohammadPasha - I updatead the answer

Comment: @thardes2 is the SUMO connection will be able to handle the three scenarios simultaneously?

Comment: @FadySamann: No, only one per simulation